# Dockerfile file not found in keycloak docker image

Tags: docker

I recently tried to clone our production code in local setup which means this code is running in production.

The docker file looks like

```
FROM jboss/keycloak

COPY km.json /opt/jboss
COPY entrypoint.sh /opt/jboss

USER root
RUN chown jboss /opt/jboss/entrypoint.sh && chmod +x /opt/jboss/entrypoint.sh
USER 1000

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/jboss/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD [""]
```

I am successfully able to create docker image but when I try to run it I get error

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: km.json (No such file or directory)
```

Repo structure

```
km/keycloak-images/km.json
km/keycloak-images/DockerFile
km/keycloak-images/entrypoint.sh
```

Docker compose file structure

```
/km/docker-compose.yml
/km/docker-compose.dev.yml
```

The docker-compose.dev.yml looks like

```
version: '3'

# The only service we expose in local dev is the keycloak server
# running an h2 database.
services:
  keycloak:
    build: keycloak-image
    image: dt-keycloak
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: h2
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME: localhost
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

I run the command from /km

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build
```

Comment: Where is `docker-compose.dev.yml`  located?

Comment: in /km directory

Answer (score 0):

Basically not able to find the file inside docker container to check.

```
$docker run --rm -it <containerName> /bin/bash #this command is used to run the docker and get inside the container.
cd /opt/jboss #check km.json file is there or not
```

Edited: Basically the path for the source in `COPY`(km.json) is incorrect. Try using absolute path the make it relative.

```
FROM jboss/keycloak

COPY ./km.json /opt/jboss # changed this line
COPY entrypoint.sh /opt/jboss

USER root
RUN chown jboss /opt/jboss/entrypoint.sh && chmod +x /opt/jboss/entrypoint.sh
USER 1000

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/jboss/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD [""]
```

Comment: this did not work. I changed Dockerfile but same error

Comment: also since I cant get container running I cant check if km.json exist. Because I get error and container exit

Comment: `docker system prune -a` then `cd km/keycloak-images/ ` then `docker build -t testName .` then `docker run --rm -it <containerName> /bin/bash` use this command to run it won't exit the container

Answer (score 0):

Your copy operation is wrong

if you run from

```
/km
```

you probably need to change COPY to

```
COPY keycloak-images/km.json /opt/jboss
```

if you run on Mac, try to use ADD instead of COPY, since mac has many issues with the copy

Comment: this fails because the file is not found using that location

Comment: can you please be specific? with "that"

Comment: keycloak-images/km.json

Comment: and COPY km.json /opt/jboss is also failing?

Comment: COPY km.json /opt/jboss is failing in local. COPY km.json /opt/jboss is running in prod btw

Comment: okay to be specific, we talk locally now only  COPY km.json /opt/jboss and COPY keycloak-images/km.json /opt/jboss are both failing locally?

Comment: are you running same docker version prod and locally? same to docker-compose?

Comment: everything is same

Comment: also the OS and the distribution version?

Comment: one is ubuntu, one is mac

Comment: and mac is failing? isn't it?

Comment: okay first take your mac and throw it away ;-) (sorry only a joke could not resist, since mac does EVERYTHING different)
Second you try to switch to ADD instead of COPY. This may fix it
Mac has multiple issues with docker. If you google for it you will find it.

Comment: I get file not found error. The compose file did work through but now back to step 1

Comment: come on, do you want to get help? Why do I need to pull everything from you. What is step 1?

Comment: Sorry step 1 I mean I get the same error of file not found

Comment: can you switch on mac only to latest docker version? what is your local docker version and docker-compose version? and what is it on production?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  keycloak:
    build: 
      context: ./keycloak-images
    image: dt-keycloak
    environment:
      - DB_VENDOR: h2
      - KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
      - KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME: localhost
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

You have to specify the docker build context so that the files you need to copy are passed to the daemon.

Note that you need to adapt this context path when you **do not execute** docke-compose from `km` directory. This is because on your dockerfile you have specified

```
COPY km.json /opt/jboss
COPY entrypoint.sh /opt/jboss
```

Saying that the build context sent to docker daemon should be a directory containing these files.

Comment: what do you mean by 'Note that you need to adapt this context path when you do not execute docke-compose from km directory.'?

Comment: The Compose file './docker-compose.dev.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.keycloak: 'context'

Comment: Using the same docker-compose like you mentioned gives 'ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "./docker-compose.dev.yml", line 8, column 14'

Comment: @ksernow Please check indentation. You may use an online yaml validator.

Comment: @ksernow Please check again.

Comment: valid yaml but still got file not found error. Kinda bummer now. Been on this for last 3 hours !

Comment: @ksernow Can you share a github repo so that I can reproduce your issue?